# Making the text in an align environment italic

Tags: math-mode, environments, italic

How can I make all the text in an align environment italic? As you can see from the code below I have started by adding \textit to each row but then when I get to making the fraction italic I get an error. Is there a better way?

```
\begin{align*}
\textit{27 + 183}
& \textit{= 210}\\
\textit{27 + 2} 
& \textit{= 29}\\
\frac{1}{2} \times 29 
&= 14.5\\
14.5 × 14.5 
& = 210.25\\
210.25 - 210 
& = 0.25\\
(0.25) 
 & = 0.5
\end{align*}
```

Comment: really you want an italic `=` ? I'd use `\mathit{27} + \mathit{2}` and `\frac{\mathit{1}}{\mathit{2}}`

Answer (score 2):

assuming you just want numbers not all symbols in italic I'd just use your editor to replace  `([0-9.]+)` by  `\\mathit{\1}` resulting in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathit{27} + \mathit{183}
&= \mathit{210}\\
\mathit{27} + \mathit{2}
& = \mathit{29}\\
\frac{\mathit{1}}{\mathit{2}} \times \mathit{29} 
&= \mathit{14.5}\\
\mathit{14.5} × \mathit{14.5} 
& = \mathit{210.25}\\
\mathit{210.25} - \mathit{210} 
& = \mathit{0.25}\\
(\mathit{0.25}) 
 & = \mathit{0.5}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```